# What is approch to consume Kafka for Java web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I made one web application in java spring mvc,

In this application traffic will be around 10000 files upload/minute.

So in controller we wrote a code to inject file byte data into Kafka Producer.

Where to implement consumer that can get result of file and do the process in java?

Need to make service which will run separately like Windows service. Is this good way?

Comment: What do you want to do when you consume a message? I think that determines where you implement it

Comment: @cricket_007 I need to get files data, process it and then store data into database

Comment: Though your consumer could run under your servlet container/application server, a standalone java application that runs as a daemon (lnx) or a service(win) sounds correct for separation of concerns. my 2 cents

Comment: This is only advantage to use Kafka or any other interesting things are there?